# How to change PdfSharp controller after changing a int to a decimal

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, pdfsharp

I changed my int to decimal? and I am now getting a error in my PdfSharp controller

```
gfx.DrawString(job.JobRetainage.ToString("C",
              new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")), BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
             new XRect(460, 160, page.Width, page.Height),
             XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

Error Message

> no overload for method tostring takes 2 arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gfx.DrawString(job.JobRetainage.Value.ToString("C",
          new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")), BodyFont, XBrushes.Black,
         new XRect(460, 160, page.Width, page.Height),
         XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

You would also want to check for null or use `GetValueOrDefault()`.